# Unearthed Arcana 5th Edition

Tags: dnd-5e

Where can I find Unearthed Arcana 5th Edition? Is it only online? I have tried looking for it online already.

Comment: What are you looking for, exactly? It sounds like maybe you're looking for a print book called *Unearthed Arcana* for 5e, like there are books called *Unearthed Arcana* for Ad&D 1st edition and D&D 3.5th edition — is that the case? Or are you looking for something else online?

Comment: What did you google? The first result after googling "unearthed arcana 5e" was the official WotC link.

Comment: Aside, welcome to the Stack. Check out the [tour] to see how the site works and what it's overall for.

Answer (score 17):

Unearthed Arcana (for D&D Fifth Edition) is not a book, it is a series of articles containing playtest versions of new rules for the game that are released as PDFs on Wizards of the Coast's D&D website. You can find the index of all the Unearthed Arcana articles [here](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/unearthed-arcana).